# Optimize SQL query from multiple tables that may be empty

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I am currently writing a query on my database (Postgres 9.5) wanting to get all information from multiple tables on a user. For example, I have a user that may have multiple pairs of shoes, personal records, be on multiple teams, etc. I have several associative tables to store the one to many relationships. I want the query to be as fast as possible, as the user may have multiple items of each table. Here is what I have currently:

```
SELECT p.username, p.sex, p.birthdate, p.firstname, p.lastname, json_agg(json_build_object('team', t.*)) as teams, json_agg(json_build_object('shoe', s.*)) as shoes, json_agg(json_build_object('pr', pr.*)) as prs, d.devicename FROM person_tbl p
LEFT JOIN person_team_tbl tp ON tp.person_id = p.person_id
LEFT JOIN team_tbl t ON tp.team_id = t.team_id
LEFT JOIN person_shoe_tbl ps on ps.person_id = p.person_id
LEFT JOIN shoe_tbl s on ps.shoe_id = s.shoe_id
LEFT JOIN person_pr_tbl ppr on ppr.person_id = p.person_id
LEFT JOIN personalrecord_tbl pr on ppr.pr_id = pr.pr_id
LEFT JOIN person_device_tbl dp on dp.person_id = p.person_id
LEFT JOIN deviceinfo_tbl d on dp.device_id = d.device_id
GROUP BY p.username, p.sex, p.birthdate, p.firstname, p.lastname, d.devicename
```

Is this the most efficient way to write the query? It returns what I need, but I want to ensure that it is written efficiently. Also, instead of returning all users, it will only return one (I haven't written that yet).

Comment: No, this is terrible. There are not many cases where many:many relation is needed and this definitly not one of them. You are creating meaningless duplications.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz - The question wasn't about whether we like his data model, it was about how to efficiently query the data model....  But setting that aside, I'm curious why you think you know enough about his data to critique the relationship cardinalities

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, I wasn't talking about is data model but about is query logic. A customer has 3 phones, 4 emails, and 5 addresses. What do you think will happen when we'll join the 3 table on customer id?

Comment: The existence of a many-to-many relationship is a data model issue.  If you want to be condescending start by using the correct terminology.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, fine with me, please suggest another term for the relation created by the OP joins.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz - The term for joining multiple tables with no correlation between those tables, and thereby getting back every possible combination, is "cross join".  Beyond that, I see you've finally decided to put useful information in an answer rather than just pointless criticism in the comments, so I'm going to leave this be from here on.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, "cross join"? but there is a correlation between the tables - only rows of the same user are being joined. But this is not a correlation of 1:1 or 1:many... maybe many:many?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz ``@MarkAdelsberger Thanks guys... I am working on changing my data model. I had it correct at one point but then got confused and changed everything. The only many:many relationships in this model are the team to users (One user can be on multiple teams, and a Team has multiple users). Everything else is a one:many relationship. I'm just deleting the associative tables as necessary and doing `LEFT JOIN shoe_tbl s on s.person_id = p.person_id`.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz - As I said, I'm done with this conversation.  If you want to believe that the existence of this query creates a many-to-many relationship, go right ahead.

Comment: It seems you are only looking for the correct term. I would call this a *partial* cross join :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner :-)

Answer (score 2):

What you have above is a query that naturally describes what data is needed; that is what you should generally strive for, and then it's up to the query optimizer to find the fastest way to run it.

In some cases you may find that you can rewrite a query to run faster, but (a) as database software gets better the cases where this matters get more obscure, and (b) it often may be a bad idea, as what tricks a cost-based optimizer into working well today may blind it into working terribly against a different set of data tomorrow.

Unless you have a definite performance problem - i.e. you can articulate a performance target and you're not meeting it - I would tread carefully.  If you do decide to optimize, there are other approaches to consider before trying to outsmart the optimizer:

1) Are indexes, statistics, and other physical model considerations as appropriate for your DBMS defined in a way that supports the query well?  I'm not an expert on Postgress in particular, but I'd think you'd want indexes on primary and foregin keys used in the query, and if the optimizer requires you to define statistics you'd want appropriate stats collected on those columns as well.

2) Is the query running in the best possible environment?  It may not be realistic to expect a heavy analytic query to run efficiently on a live transactional system or an underpowered server

Answer (score 2):

See edited answer.

```
select      p.username, p.sex, p.birthdate, p.firstname, p.lastname
           ,t.teams,s.shoes,pr.prs
           ,d.devicename 

from                            person_tbl p

            left join lateral  (select  json_agg(json_build_object('team', t.* )) as teams 
                                from            person_team_tbl tp  
                                        join    team_tbl        t 
                                        on      tp.team_id = t.team_id
                                where   tp.person_id = p.person_id
                                ) t on true

            left join lateral  (select  json_agg(json_build_object('shoe', s.* )) as shoes 
                                from            person_shoe_tbl ps
                                        join    shoe_tbl        s  
                                        on      ps.shoe_id = s.shoe_id
                                where   ps.person_id = p.person_id
                                ) s on true

            left join lateral  (select  json_agg(json_build_object('pr', pr.*)) as prs 
                                from            person_pr_tbl       ppr
                                        join    personalrecord_tbl  pr 
                                        on      ppr.pr_id = pr.pr_id
                                where   ppr.person_id = p.person_id
                                ) pr on true

            left join           person_device_tbl   dp  on dp.person_id     = p.person_id
            left join           deviceinfo_tbl      d   on dp.device_id     = d.device_id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with aggregates from different tables it is a good habit to join the aggregates rather than build a big intermediate result of all record combinations before aggregating. (This also helps getting sums and counts straight when working with these.) If I had to write the query, it would look thus:

```
SELECT 
  p.username, p.sex, p.birthdate, p.firstname, p.lastname, 
  teams.json_team as teams, 
  shoes.json_shoe as shoes, 
  precs.json_prec as prs, 
  d.devicename
FROM person_tbl p
LEFT JOIN person_device_tbl dp on dp.person_id = p.person_id
LEFT JOIN deviceinfo_tbl d on dp.device_id = d.device_id
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT pt.person_id, json_agg(json_build_object('team', t.*)) as json_team
  FROM person_team_tbl pt
  JOIN team_tbl t ON t.team_id = pt.team_id
  GROUP BY pt.person_id
) teams ON teams.person_id = p.person_id
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT ps.person_id, json_agg(json_build_object('shoe', s.*)) as json_shoe
  FROM person_shoe_tbl ps
  JOIN shoe_tbl s on s.shoe_id = ps.shoe_id
  GROUP BY ps.person_id
) shoes ON shoes.person_id = p.person_id
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT ppr.person_id, json_agg(json_build_object('pr', pr.*)) as json_prec
  FROM person_pr_tbl ppr 
  JOIN personalrecord_tbl pr on pr.pr_id = ppr.pr_id
  GROUP BY ppr.person_id
) precs ON precs.person_id = p.person_id;
```